# When deleting a directory and then recreating it, how can I avoid getting these error messages?

Tags: warning-messages, files-and-directories, windows

I need to create a directory with a name which may or may not already exist, so I'm starting by checking whether it does exist and, if it does, deleting it. But I'm still getting error messages. How can I avoid this?

This is my code:

```
pSite = FileNameJoin[{DriveLetter, "this", "directory"}];
If[DirectoryQ[pSite] == True, DeleteDirectory[pSite, DeleteContents -> True], ""];
CreateDirectory[pSite];
```

These are the error messages I'm getting:

```
DeleteDirectory::dirne: Directory C:\this\directory not empty. >>
CreateDirectory::filex: C:\this\directory\ already exists. >>
```

I'm using Mathematica 9 on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Are you sure none of the files are in use?  Open files generally cannot be deleted on Windows (unlike the other platforms).

Comment: @ihojnicki - Ah, you're right! The error messages only come when at least one of the files is open. But the program still does what it should, including altering the open file, so how can I get rid of the error messages without first ensuring that none of the files are open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The error messages only come when at least one of the files is open. But the program still does what it should, including altering the open file, so how can I get rid of the error messages without first ensuring that none of the files are open?

Use [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html):

```
Quiet @ DeleteDirectory[pSite, DeleteContents -> True]
If[! DirectoryQ[pSite], CreateDirectory[pSite]];
```

Though it isn't clear why you still wish to modify a file in a directory you wish to delete with its contents.

Comment: Excellent - many thanks!

Comment: What I've said about `Quiet[]` way way back applies here: "it's a convenient way to lie to yourself that your code works". (@ruffle)

Comment: @J.M. :-) Yes, it does seem a bit like stopping one's ears when error messages appear, but in this case I blame Windows!